# Visual Studio 2013 - Cleanly disabling VSTEST Discovery Engine?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vs-unit-testing-framework, vstest

Quick question about VS2013 settings - is there a way to disable the VSTEST Discovery engine from starting on/after build?

I've never had this process running as a child-process of VS2013 before, however I recently created a unit-test project in VS2013 for a demo and now in every solution I load (whether it has a unit-test project or not) the vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe runs whenever I build a project.

Is there a way to switch it off? I've turned the "Test->Keep Test Execution Engine" option off in the test menu, even using a taskkill pre and post build event doesn't stop it running (it seems to respawn after a successful build, after the post-build event).

I could always delete or rename the file manually, but I'm wondering if anyone knows a setting or option in VS2013 to switch it off rather than actually going to the trouble of renaming/deleting a file which could potentially cause VS2013 updates to break...

Thanks in advance for a response!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up renaming the file manually in the file-system, this stopped it from loading every time Visual Studio 2013 started.. So far I haven't had any issues/side-effects from doing this, however I haven't built another unit-test project since the first one I tried... still would like to hear from anyone if they've managed to stop this process loading automatically without having to resort to manual file renaming as I have done.

So what I did was rename:
**vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe** 
to: 
**vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe.foo**

Comment: This works for me. Only side effect is the output window now complains about file not being found. This dramatically decreased debugging time. Thanks!

Comment: Had to rename a few of them (32 bit and 64 bit). Just keep Task Manager open on a full rebuild and you'll see them spike CPU on the process. Open File Location to identify the exact file; terminate the process then add the `.old` extension, etc.